# System freezes with heavy disk usage - Samsung Series 9

Tags: freeze, samsung, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I've recently purchased a Samsung Series 9 and put Ubuntu 12.04 on it. I installed Ubuntu via the windows installer.

Everything mostly works great, other than the occasional system freeze.

The system will freeze when copying large files to a different location on the same disk, or when performing any sort of heavy disk usage, like installing new packages from Update manager. If I copy a large file to the windows partition from Ubuntu, then everything works fine. I'm assuming it's related to the SSD. The SSD is ATA SanDisk 128GB. What can I do to resolve this?